# Ajax PHP printing error inside paragraph

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form where the user has to enter their reservation id and last name. If these two values match in the database then I need to return the corresponding values from the database.

I am trying to print the error inside a paragraph if the reservation or last name don't match. I do see the error in the console but not inside the page.

It looks like even if the wrong reservation id and name are put in, it treats it as success. The page reloads even when it's wrong.

Here is my code

```
<p id='guest_full_name'></p>
<p id='unit_number'></p>
<p id='floor'></p>
<p id='error'></p>

<script>
function validateReservation(){
  var reservation_id = document.getElementById("reservation_id").value;
  var guest_last_name = document.getElementById("guest_last_name").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test06.php',
        // dataType: 'json',
        data: {
                'reservation_id': reservation_id,
                'guest_last_name' : guest_last_name
            }, 
        success: function(json) {
            var json = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log(json);
            $('#guest_full_name').html(json.guest_full_name);
            $('#unit_number').html(json.unit_number);   
            $('#floor').html(json.floor);
            $('#key_sa').html(json.key_sa);
            }, 
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            $("#error").html("Error!");
            } 
    }); 
}
```

test06.php

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

$reservation_id=$_POST['reservation_id'];
$guest_last_name=$_POST['guest_last_name'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT reservation_id, guest_last_name, guest_full_name, unit_number, floor, key_sa 
                        FROM reservations2 
                            INNER JOIN guest ON (reservations2.reservation_id=guest.reservation_idg) 
                            INNER JOIN unit USING (unit_id) 
                        WHERE reservation_id=? 
                        AND guest_last_name=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $reservation_id, $guest_last_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($reservation_id, $guest_last_name, 
                   $guest_full_name, $unit_number,  
                   $floor, $key_sa);
if ($stmt->errno) {
    die("Query failed to execute: " . $stmt->error);
}
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo json_encode(array("reservation_id" => $reservation_id, 
                           "guest_last_name" => $guest_last_name,  
                           "guest_full_name" => $guest_full_name,  
                           "unit_number" => $unit_number,  
                           "floor" => $floor,  
                           "key_sa" => $key_sa));
} else {
    $error="Not matching record";
    echo json_encode($error);
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: json_encode it too

Comment: This is not related to your problem but just FYI you are pulling what looks like user-entered data back from the database and displaying it on your page as html. This opens you up to cross site scripting exploits. Assuming you arent relying on this you should use jQueries [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) instead. It automatically encodes HTML for you.

Comment: @Bernhard I updated the code, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no server error, hence it was not printing it. I had to send the status code in order for it to work

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
http_response_code(500); 
echo $json;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to see the error inside of the element with the `error` id attribute, then use the same `err` variable instead of the word error (unless I'm misunderstanding something).

This is your original code:

```
error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    $("#error").html("Error!"); //<-- Replace this...
}
```

Try this updated code:

```
error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    $('#error').text(err); //<-- ...with this.
}
```

Comment: I also tried this, it is not working. I am not getting the error inside the paragraph

Comment: I made a couple updates. Not that I think the first will fix your code, but just for continuity's sake being that you've used single quotes in the `success` portion of the AJAX call, change it in the `error` portion as well.

Try changing the `.html()` to `.text()`.

Comment: It looks like even if the wrong reservation id and name are put in, it treats it as success. The page reloads even when it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If in the console you see the data of the variable `json`, then I think the problem is the MIME type that the browser detects when making the AJAX call.

That is, when you call a web page (php or html), the server in the header of the response tells the browser that the information it returns is a `text/html`.

Therefore, in PHP, you can tell the client (the browser that receives the data) that it is of the type `application/json`.

At the beginning of your PHP code add:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

***test06.php***

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // <-- MIME JSON
$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");
$reservation_id=$_POST['reservation_id'];
$guest_last_name=$_POST['guest_last_name'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare(QUERY);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $reservation_id, $guest_last_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result(VARS);
if ($stmt->errno) {
    die("Query failed to execute: " . $stmt->error);
}
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo json_encode(ARRAY);
} else {
    $error="Not matching record";
    echo json_encode($error);
}
$stmt->close();
```

**Remember NOT to leave blanks before** `<?php`**.**

Comment: I tried this, it's not working. I am still getting the error in the console but not the paragraph on th epage

Comment: Can you share the **URL**? I want see response.

Comment: For security purposes, I can't

Comment: Don't worry. Show me a screenshot of the request:
https://i.imgur.com/4pvarAS.png
1. Press F12.
2. Click Network.
3. Click XHR.
4. Click request (ajax).
5. Find Content Type, and share screenshot.